# What are some techniques to infer the subnet being used?

Tags: ip, ipv4, subnet

Given a list of thousands of IPv4 addresses and that you have no direct access to these hosts, is there a service or a methodology to infer a subnet that's possibly being used?

Comment: *no direct access to these hosts* then it's not a network you manage, and therefore off topic.

Answer (score 1):

No. You can’t infer the subnet from the IP address alone.

Comment: The best one can hope for is to find the block to which the address belongs via WHOIS. But that won't tell you a LAN netmask.

Comment: @RickyBeam Another source would be the ASN table but that's likely even less granular than Whois.

Comment: @Zac67 and the way people "protect" their address space, BGP will show everything as a /24.